# Can you have a schema or folder structure in AWS Athena?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, aws-glue

I am copying an entire snowflake DB into S3 to be viewed through Athena. I would like to preserve the schema/hierarchy so that the corresponding queries do not change. All the files are organized properly for this in S3 as follows

DataBase/Schema/Folder/Table/{parquet files}

When I crawl with Glue they all end up in one DB at the same level. Is it possible to have a similar folder structure in Athena?

Right now all queries in Athena are like

```
Select *
FROM database.table
```

I would like to have

```
Select *
FROM database.schema.folder.table
```

Comment: "To influence the crawler to create separate tables, add each table's root folder as a separate data store when you define the crawler." , Check this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/crawler-s3-folder-table-partition.html

Comment: I think you misunderstand. I want the folder structure in athena. I am getting all my tables correctly. They just all appear in the same directory.

Comment: What do you mean by "appear in the same directory"? Are you referring to the sidebar in the Amazon Athena management console? Athena has the concept of a "Database", but it does not have any additional levels of hierarchy.

Comment: Yes, can I get more levels of hierarchy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only logical grouping of tables available in [Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/work-with-data.html) is a `database`, and as you have indicated, there is no concept of hierarchy, schemas, or folders in Athena.

Database and schema comprise a [namespace](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/ddl-database.html) in Snowflake. If your intention is to simply have a similar namespace, what you can do is combine the Snowflake database `d1` and schema name `s1` to create a flattened logical grouping in Athena `d1_s1`. Then you can do:

```
SELECT * FROM d1_s1.table
```

Also, the only special character you can have in the database name is an [underscore](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/tables-databases-columns-names.html), so there really is no other way to preserve the structure or the existing queries. At least, this way the format is close enough that it should be easy enough to programmatically fix the existing queries (e.g., using regex to replace `a.b.c` with `a_b.c`).

However, there will still be differences. For example, [grants](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-configure.html#creating-managed-access-schemas) are managed differently for Snowflake databases and schemas. Schemas also have a concept of `managed access`. This will not be possible in Athena.

Comment: Great answer, @Register Sole   . Do you know if this was a design decision or if it is a technological constraint? If it is possible I will submit a feature request. It seems like something many people would desire.

Comment: @Keith Athena is based on PrestoDB. PrestoDB has `connector` and `schema`, so the namespace looks like `postgresql.schema1.table2`. These translate directly to Athena [`data source` and `database`](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/extracting-and-joining-data-from-multiple-data-sources-with-athena-federated-query/). So the most obvious reason to me is inheritance from the parent project. As to why PrestoDB does that, I'm guessing that having 2 levels of logical grouping on top of a connector (`connector1.db3.schema2.table8`) makes it too complex and defeats the purpose of logical grouping.

Comment: I would settle for 2 levels. At the moment I only have 1. I use the Database for different projects which I do not want to mix. I may submit a feature request. It does not sound like this is impossible to solve.